# Error "no such identity: ... /.ssh/ id_rsa_gitlab"

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I accidentally deleted my *id_rsa_gitlab* file, and when I wanted to clone from GitLab, I received this error.

```
no such identity:/Users/directory/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab: No such file or directory
```

I'm new to pipelines, and I tried to follow tutorials on how to configure *.ssh*, but it's just the *id_rsa* file that gets configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command would be:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f /Users/directory/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab
```

That would restore a private/public key, and you need to register the public key to your account.

Check which `Host` entry references that private key in your `/Users/directory/.ssh/config` file.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new SSH key and add it to your GitLab repository.

See *[Adding your SSH key to GitLab](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application-development/9781783986842/2/ch02lvl1sec20/adding-your-ssh-key-to-gitlab)*.